# meaning of "otherwise"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In Alaska, tradition is a powerful legal concept, appearing in a wide
>   variety of legal contexts relating to natural-resource and
>   public-lands activities. Both state and federal laws in the United
>   States assign privileges and exemptions to individuals engaged in
>   "traditional" activities **using otherwise off-limits land and
>   resources.**

I am having a hard time understanding the bold part, especially because of the word "otherwise". Can someone help me understand this part?

Answer (score 2):

"Otherwise" as a modifier like this means "which would otherwise be".

So "otherwise off-limits land and resources" means "land and resources which would otherwise be off-limits", i.e. if they were not engaged in "traditional" activities.

Answer (score 0):

[..] individuals engaged in "traditional" activities using otherwise off-limits land and resources

Otherwise here means: only the fact that you engage in "traditional" activities allows you to use off-limits land and resources.